# Need help for a regex : set-publicitaire-securite-enfant/objet-test/35687

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http-status-code-410

I have to process a large set of 404, they must match with this type of url :

set-publicitaire-securite-enfant/objet-test/35687

Before the first slash you can find any type of character, including numbers. After the first slash the character string will necessarily be "objet-test" and after the last slash there'll necessarily be numbers (but I don't know exactly how many).

Thank you in advance

I'm waiting for a rule that'll proposes any type of URL looks like this must be redirected in 410 in the .htaccess

Comment: Try this: `^.+?\/objet-test\/\d+$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^.+?\/objet-test\/\d+$
```

See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/yh8vSN/1).